# The method getRequest() from the type BaseAction refers to the missing type HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, servlets

```
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The method getRequest() from the type BaseAction 
refers to the missing type HttpServletRequest
```

and this is the method:

```
public String list(){

    QueryFilter filter=new QueryFilter(getRequest());
    filter.addSorted("rowNumber", "asc");
    List<Section> list= sectionService.getAll(filter);

    Type type=new TypeToken<List<Section>>(){}.getType();
    StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer("{success:true,'totalCounts':")
    .append(filter.getPagingBean().getTotalItems()).append(",result:");

    Gson gson=new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
    buff.append(gson.toJson(list, type));
    SysConfig sectionColumn = sysConfigService.findByKey("sectionColumn");
    buff.append(",columnType:");
    if(sectionColumn!=null){
        buff.append(sectionColumn.getDataValue());
    }else{
        buff.append("2");
    }
    buff.append("}");

    jsonString=buff.toString();

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score -5):

add a servlet api to your classpath. This will solve the problem

Comment: Your answer would be more helpful if you *explain* **how**. There are namely many ways to achieve this, including utterly wrong ways.

Comment: @BalusC More details are needed to properly answer how to add a jar to the classpath. I was hoping that the question starter will update his / her question.

Comment: Post a comment on the question for clarification if you can't answer the question in its current form.

Comment: I'm not saying that your answer is wrong. It's just far from complete and below the standards of Stack Exchange. You're nowhere **explaining** the why and the how.

Comment: @BalusC the user gets what's asking for.